# How to convert 7.62cm linear motion to 150-180° rotary motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, actuator

I need to convert 7.62cm/3in linear motion from an actuator to 150-180° (150 is minimum) rotary motion. I am aware of the existence of gears, but would probe here to see if there is some simpler method. I could use rods mounted in some way. It has to be compact and rugged, however. I'd also be interested in formulas for this type of conversion. Thanks!

Edit: 
I found this contraption [image: Mystery device] for microlinear precision, whilst googling for scotch yoke. Is this a scotch yoke? If not, what is it? I can probably awfulhack one of these with a file, some aluminium rods and strips. But it would be prettier if I bought one.

Comment: You won't need gears as there are commonly used methods often used in backhoes and cherry picker trucks to move the arms almost 180 degrees with a single hydraulic piston. I have not tried the drawing tools here yet so I will leave it to others to provide more detail. But if you search for photos of backhoes or power line maintenance trucks you will see a type of linkage that does what you need.

Comment: @Entrepreneur Well, this is a linear actuator. I suppose the same principle applies. Can you provide a link to what you mention?

Comment: Another simple way to convert linear motion into rotary motion is with a scotch yoke, look up the Bourke Engine to see how these operate.

Comment: it is essentially a rack and pinion with different gear shape than the typcal involute. In this case a cycloid function, which is the second common, but considerablybrarer gear shape.

Comment: This youtube video is crude but you can definitely see the 3 moving parts and how they interact. The red line is the hydraulic cylinder. The white line is a link that connects the 2 green arms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb4jiscwhvw

Comment: Here is another youtube video that is helpful. The link proportions and pivot points are way off. But the essential pieces are there and the concept is the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09jZsBDHalE&list=PL_AXzsnrjstigELkDUtQINEmLcngU53FD

Comment: @Entrepreneur Thanks, post this backhoe as a potential answer please. I will wait another day to see what else reveals itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested a rack and pinion will provide a linear transfer function and avoids complex linkages. A variant on the rack and pinion is to replace the straight rack teeth with a taught cable and the pinion teeth with a pulley. This mechanism is sometimes referred to as a capstan and bowstring.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capstan_and_Bowstring

If you need a guarantee against slippage then the cable can be wrapped multiple times and attached to the pulley at the half-way point.

Answer (score 2):

There are commonly used methods used in backhoes and cherry picker trucks to move the arms about 180 degrees with a single hydraulic piston. If you search for photos of backhoes or power line maintenance trucks you may see a type of linkage.

Here is a photo

[image]

This video is crude but you can definitely see the 3 moving parts and how they interact. The red line is the hydraulic cylinder. The white line is a link that connects the 2 green arms.

[backhoe linkage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb4jiscwhvw)

In this second video the link proportions and pivot points are way off. But the essential pieces are there and the concept is the same.

[Converting Linear to Rotary motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09jZsBDHalE&list=PL_AXzsnrjstigELkDUtQINEmLcngU53FD)

The transfer function won't be linear though.

Comment: What about a small rack and pinion then?